# What's the difference between environment and memory in terms of programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages

I've been reading up on programming languages to better my understanding with the textbook *Essentials of Programming Languages (3e) - Friedman & Wand*.

In a chapter regarding the states of languages (i.e. when we account for the effects that a computation may have rather than the immediately evaluated value), I've noticed that the terms **environment** and **memory** are used frequently, but I'm not sure how to grasp the difference.

> According to the text, **"an environment associates a value with each element of a finite set of variables,"** and **"memory is a finite map from locations to a set of values called stored values."**

Does this mean that environments are a part of memory? The part that especially confuses me is when we **"extend the environment."**

To give a short example, if I had a procedure such that

```ocaml
let f = proc (x) (x + 1) in
  f (1)
```

then the text states that we "extend our environment" so variable `f` points to a location (say, `l1`) and argument `x` points to `l2`.

`l1` in turn points to the procedure tuple `(x, (x + 1), empty_env)`, and finally `l2` points to the actual argument `1`.

We update the location contents according to the procedure, which means we update `l2` with `2`, and the program finally returns `2`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Functions

The terms "*associate*" and "*map*" together with "finite" indicate that both definitions refer to *finite mathematical functions*.

A (mathematical) **function** is a *relation* that *associates* each *element* of a *set*, the **domain** of the *function*, to a *single element* of another *set* (possibly the same *set*), the **codomain** of the *function* [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))].

Another way to put this, for **finite functions** are: a *finite set* of *ordered pairs*.

**Map** is usually *defined* as a synonym to *function*.

Thus the definitions could be rewritten as follows:

---

### Environment

An **environment** is a *finite function* that *associates* each *element* in the *finite set of variables* (**domain**), to a *single element* in the *finite set of values* (**codomain**). The **range** would be the *set of all possible values* (possibly *infinite*).

### Memory

A **memory** is a *finite function* that *associates* each *element* in the *finite set of locations* (**domain**), to a *single element* in the *finite set of stored values* (**codomain**). The **range** would be the *set of all possible values* (possibly *infinite*).

---

## Sets

> Does this mean that environments are a part of memory?

Since this is about *sets*, if you by *part* mean **subset**, then the answer would be no.

However, the *codomains* are definitely related, if a *variable* is *associated* with a *value* in the *environment*, a *location* must also be *associated* to a *stored value* in the *memory*, that corresponds to the *variable value*.

---

## Extending the Environment

> The part that especially confuses me is when we "extend the environment."

It seems the aim of the text is to build an *interpreter*. You start out with no *variables declared* (including procedures), i.e., an **empty environment** and then you *interpret/parse/analyze* the *code* to make these *associations*, i.e., **extending the environment**.

---

## In Practice

It might be helpful to think of the **memory** as the *values stored* somewhere in the *physical memory* and the **environment** as the *values* that the *interpreted process* currently knows about.

---