# What is the precise difference between state and environment and memory?

Tags: programming-languages, static-analysis

I was just reading [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/99849/66333) question regarding the difference between **environment** and **memory**. However, the textbook in question, *Essentials of Programming Languages*, third edition, by Friedman and Wand, also has chapter **4 State**, which, as it says, discussed the concept of **state**. But, as far as I can tell, it doesn't seem to explicitly differentiate between **environment**, **memory**, and **state**, and it is unclear to me what the difference is. What is the precise difference between **state** and **environment** and **memory**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very informally:

An **environment** is a set of pairs (variable+value) that are accessible to a particular object/process during its execution.

A **memory** is a set of "locations" in which an object/process can read/store information. Usually a location is associated with a variable and the value of the variable is stored in that location (or in several locations).

The **state** of an object/system is the set of values of the properties (variables) of the object/system in a particular point in time (during an execution or process).

The big picture:

- variables are logical "names" for values that can change in time (modified during the execution). They are called *constants* (from the viewpoint of a particular object/process) if the object/process cannot modify them.
- environment refers to a set of variables from the viewpoint of an object/process; the object/process can read or (if allowed) modify them. Note that the emphasis, when talking about "environment", is usually on the "variables", not their (current) values.
- memory is the place where variables are stored. Note that memory is a concept that is at a lower (implementation) level. To define a high-level programming language there is no need to "talk about memory" unless you need to implement it on a real architecture; but it can be useful to understand other concepts such as variables or arrays.
- state is a "dump" ("snapshot") of the variables+current values (hence implicitly also a dump of the memory where they are stored) in a particular point in time of the execution/process

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can consider state and environment to be the same thing. The difference is mostly when writing logical deductions. The environment is the context that makes a given proposition true and may be a just a part of the global state. What memory introduces is **aliasing**; $A[i] = x$ may be falsified by a preceding $A[j] \leftarrow y$ if $i = j$. Without memory you don't have aliasing and the value of a variable is always the last value assigned to it.